# Probability that the drawn ball is the only ball of its kind.

Tags: probability, elementary-probability

A bag contains 7 balls of any colour. A ball is drawn at random  and is found to be of blue colour. Find the probability that it is the only blue coloured ball.

I am not getting a start. Like do we apply bayes theorem here or bernaulli's trial of successes. Pls help.

Comment: Do we have any more information? What colors are available to the balls (is blue one of 3 possible colors? 6? 7? 256?)? How likely is a ball to be a specific color (is it the same likelihood for each available color?)?

Comment: Nothing else is known. actually the question was on coins. Instead of blue ball we had a cent over there. Rest everything is same. Things look nice in case of balls lol.

Comment: You need a prior on the distribution of colors.  Perhaps the coin context supplies a natural prior?

Comment: @user354545 With only that many information, it's impossible to determine the probability. Basically $p \times (1-p)^6$ for $p$ being blue probability of each ball.

Comment: @lulu i think both cases are identical enough

Comment: Absent a prior there is no way to proceed.  You could simply make one up...declaring, for example, that a priori each possible number of blues (from $0$ to $7$) is equiprobable.  Seems arbitrary to me, but you need something like that.

Comment: @lulu so can we do the question assuming that?

Comment: Sure, use Bayes' Theorem.  But, honestly, it seems like an entirely arbitrary assumption.  A better assumption would be that there are $k$ equiprobable colors from which you drew your sample (so you'd get a binomial distribution with success probability $\frac 1k$) but I have no guess as to which $k$ you should use.  Alternatively, you could just assume that a randomly selected ball (from all the balls in the world) is blue with probability $p$.  That again yields a binomial prior, but I have no guess what $p$ might be.